# Como pegar o valor achado pelo indexOf?

Tags: javascript

Estou com um código onde passo um valor e eu preciso verificar se esse valor existe dentro do `array`, assim utilizo o `indexOf`. O que eu gostaria é pegar o valor que o `indexOf` achar, por exemplo:

```
org = 3;
var array_t = [1,2,3,4,5];

receb = (array_t.indexOf(org));
```

Nesse caso ele vai mostrar que o **3** está na posição **2**. O que eu quero é pegar o valor **3**. É possível?

Comment: Mas você já tem o 3, porque você iria querer pegar o 3? '-'

Comment: Calma .. Fui redundante perguntando '-'
 Irei me refazer aqui'

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm... o valor que você passa para o método é o valor que ele acha (se achar), por isso já tem o valor que procura certo?

Mas pode sempre fazer assim (ainda que seja redundante):

```
org = 3;
var array_t = [1,2,3,4,5];
receb = array_t.indexOf(org);

var valorAchado = array_t[receb]; // dá 3
```